# Is use of virtual reality to explore taboo activities a good idea?

Tags: society, humans, psychology, crime, virtual-reality

Let us suppose that virtual reality affecting all senses in a way virtually indistinguishable from reality exists.

Using this virtual reality, it would be possible for people with extreme, taboo fetishes - such as murder, cannibalism, rape, suicide, torture and the like to explore their fetishes in an environment in which no real person is harmed, or in the case of self-destructive fetishes, the person is not permanently harmed.  When exiting the virtual reality, nothing is brought out except that which can be remembered or learned.  You can't get injured - or increase your level of physical fitness - in this VR.

My question is: Is it a good idea to let people indulge in these sorts of extreme taboo fetishes in VR?

Please consider that:

1. The scenarios may be set up to mirror reality as closely as required, or may be set up with different social, physiological and/or physical laws.
2. Some people indulging in their taboo fetishes in VR may never have done so in the real world.
3. This hyper-real VR may or may not be readily available.  A user may indulge in their particular taboo fetish in VR only to find that the next time they have the urge to indulge, the VR is unavailable... or is expensive beyond their means.

What advantages, and particularly *disadvantages* might this bring to the real world?  In particular, would use of this sort of VR make it more likely for users to escalate to the real world if it becomes unavailable?

The context for this in my world is that a character with rather more knowledge and understanding of human psychology than my own is trying to decide whether to implement such a VR setup, for which they will be the sole provider for the foreseeable future.

The answer to this question will determine if it is implemented, and if so, the likely frequency of breaches of VR activity to the 'real' world.

Comment: Not enough for an answer: I think the answer will be something like possibly for the vast majority of people. The ones you'd need to worry about are the ones for whom VR won't satisfy for long. Just observe the VR logs for young boys who like to explore "animal cruelty" and "arson". See [MacDonald Triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macdonald_triad) et relq.

Comment: You just described the plot and moral conflict of Westworld S1 & S2. You might argue S2 starts to focus on AI rights, but if you follow William's story it challenges the very moral implications of a real human indulging on such activities this way. Also, if the VR environment becomes so real, who is to say a VR AI is any less real than a physical robot AI?

Comment: Kind of hard to say.  Certainly, past fears that sociopathic behavior in in the crude imaginary reality provided by video games would result in an uptick real-world sociopathic behavior don't seem to have been realized.  However, with a full-realism VR environment that you envision, the breakdown of the users' ability to distinguish between fantasy and reality may be much stronger and VR behavior may indeed leak into the real world.

Comment: @elemtilas That was kinda my idea, but I wanted to see if someone else would come up with it unprompted.  It's not the majority that I'm worried about, but the minority who will let their VR activities spill over into reality.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief Let's not worry about the VR NPCs.  That's an issue of the technology that isn't a factor in this question.

Comment: In what way is this a world-building question?

Comment: @Mary, the answer to this question affects the development of my world.  If implemented, such VR may result in people with certain taboo fantasies being put into an environment which seems designed to cause them to escalate their behavior... perhaps even induce them to start acting out their behavior in the first place.  I'm no expert on psychology, hence the question.  The answers will help me decide whether to implement this idea.

Comment: VTC:  This is definitely an interesting question, but as stated it's merely regurgitating very well known philosophical and ethical questions.  There's no nexus to specific 'in my world' details that would make it belong here and not (say) the Philosophy stack exchange.

Comment: @TonDay Have a look at my edit for the desired context.

Comment: I'm still not sure that's not *also* problematic by way of being opinion-based, but if you are specifically looking for psychological expertise, that's not something I have.  Vote retracted.

Comment: It is legal to play [*Grand Theft Auto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto), at least in all countries that I know of. On the other hand, in at least one rich and very powerful country it is illegal to make, distribute, or possess "a visual depiction of any kind, including a drawing, cartoon, sculpture or painting" that "depicts a minor engaging in sexually explicit conduct and is obscene" (Wikipedia, quoting the U.S. [PROTECT Act of 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROTECT_Act_of_2003)). Which means that no consensus exist regarding "taboo activities" in general.

Comment: *"People with certain taboo fantasies being put into an environment which seems designed to cause them to escalate their behavior":* which is used as a sort-of-cure in Anthony Burgess's famous [*Clockwork Orange*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(novel)) (1962), with an equally famous [film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(film)) by Stanley Kubrick (1971).

Comment: It would be best to include some way to track and monitor the use. How people react upon having done X can be very telling. Someone who has no reactions would be the person to watch out for.

Comment: VTC (but reluctantly)  "Good idea" - good for who or what and how is that measured?  How can "goodness" be assessed for each of billions of different individuals and the different societies they are part of?  A more answerable question would be whether the availability of this technology would make VR participants in taboo activities more likely to indulge them in the real world. Although that question may be viewed as opinion-based, I believe it is answerable (and would submit an answer).

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but I don't think that this type of stuff could realistically be banned. For a mild example, just look at countries where pornography is banned. For a more extreme example, there are still gladiatorial rings where slaves fight to the death for the wealthy audience's amusement in third world countries and human trafficking rings exist.

The true depths of depravity that would be available in such a VR system--even if banned--would be nigh unfathomable.

That said, I don't think the true danger is letting people indulge in this type of stuff, I think **the true danger is making regular people into psychopaths** with this type of VR: In an extreme, black-mirror-esque example, you could trap someone in a VR where they are repeatedly forced to commit heinous crimes like killing their whole family or something similar until they break, and then logging them out of VR upon which they actually go out and kill their family for real. In a less extreme, but just as insidious example, a malevolent developer could create a scenario that ramps up violence over time, thus desensitizing the person to extreme acts of violence over the course of a couple years. It's also easily imaginable that a lot of youth-hazing could be done with such a VR system, where instead of being dared to spray paint something or vandalize property IRL, kids partake in a virtual murder gauntlet to show how tough they are (or are trapped in one as a prank).

Comment: "...the true danger is making regular people into psychopaths with this type of VR: In an extreme, black-mirror-esque example, you could trap someone in a VR where they are repeatedly forced to commit heinous crimes like killing their whole family or something similar until they break, and then logging them out of VR upon which they actually go out and kill their family for real." Harvester smiles deeply.

Answer (score 2):

Some but not all serial killers show an escalation of violence. This can be detected and the mental health system can intervene (if the society has decided to have such a system). Your scenario would lead to 'socially acceptable' ways to escalate all the way to a fake serial killing that has just one little flaw -- the perpetrator **knows** it is all fake. What percentage of the VR killers goes real?

Your setting could have many of the debates we have today regarding 'social' media. Is it all covered by free speech? Is there a right to remain anonymous, so that even speech which isn't coverd by free speech has no consequences? Can police agencies monitor, or will they have to rely on friendly foreign countries that don't hesitate to monitor 'abroad' for warnings? Would a history of virtual slayings be admissible evidence in court?

Comment: I'm also concerned with the 'I wouldn't do it IRL' types, who aren't tempted bacause it's illegal or would hurt people.  Given the opportunity to do 'it' in VR where legality isn't an issue, and no-one really gets hurt, could they develop a need to do 'it' IRL if VR wasn't available?

Comment: @MontyWild, the type you describe would be a potential perpetrator who got caught *very* early by the social health monitoring. There is a proverb that all children are psychopaths, but they are usually taught better as they grow up.

Comment: Not necessarily... I'm thinking more an adult who has never been tempted to do their 'it' IRL because "it wouldn't be right", but who gets to do 'it' in VR and really enjoys it, and then can't go back into VR for whatever reason... could they escalate to IRL, and how likely would that be?

Answer (score 2):

**Perscription Only**

One downside might be the most effective (realistic) programs are prescription-only.

For example there is a program for child sexual abuse which can be prescribed to people with paedophilic urges. The reasoning is that they are less likely to express their urges in real life if they have a safe space to do it harmlessly. Likewise for the other dark fantasy programs.

The problem is this creates a system of gatekeeping that is subject to the corruption or incompetence of whoever is doing the prescribing.

Comment: And if a person with such urges used the VR and then found it unavailable?   Would they switch to doing it IRL?

Comment: @MontyWild Perhaps they would. It is up to your imagination!